# How to move cursor to the side edge of the emacs window when text is truncated?

Tags: emacs

When text is truncated like below image , I want to move cursor to `A` or `E` side edge of the emacs window. Is there any way to do this? I'm using emacs 25.

[image: Emacs GUI Window]

Comment: `C-a` to move to the beginning of the line. `C-e` to move to the end of the line.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun move-to-right-window-edge ()
  (interactive)
  (move-to-column (+ (window-text-width) (window-hscroll))))

(defun move-to-left-window-edge ()
  (interactive)
  (move-to-column (window-hscroll)))
```

You will probably want to play around with `hscroll-margin`, `hscroll-step`, and `auto-scroll-mode`.  I would recommend something like

```
(setq hscroll-margin 0
      hscroll-step 1
      auto-hscroll-mode t)
```